# mongoose findOneandUpdate math operation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to do something in Mongoose (and in general other databases) but this step I did not figure it out yet.

basically I have the following query

```
const a1 = await model.findOne({type: 3}).skip(random)
a1.views = a1.views - 1
await a1.save()
return a1
```

but what I am interested in achieving is

```
const a1 = await model.findOneAndUpdate({type: 3},{views: views--}, {new: true})
return a1
```

however of course mongoose complains that views is undefined (since it was not defined before). Any suggestions how to accomplish this on the second way?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator to increase/decrease a field by a specified value.

```
const a1 = await model.findOneAndUpdate(
     {type: 3},
     {
        $inc: {views : -1} // increase by -1 means decrease by 1
     }, 
     {new: true}
)
return a1
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. What about more complex operations like views*3?

Comment: You have $mul operator https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/mul/#mongodb-update-up.-mul. You can find a lot of information on the document page :)